# Simplifying a log expression

Tags: logarithms

$$\log_a 0.5 + \log_a 4a - \log_a b - \log_a3b$$

My attempt :

$\log_a (0.5 . 4a) - \log_a \frac{b}{3b} $

$ \log_a \frac{2a x 3b}{b} = \log_a 6a$

Why is my answer wrong ?

According to the book , I'm suppose to get -

$$ \log_a \frac{0.5 x 4a}{b x 3a} $$

Why is there a multiply sign in the denominator ? There is only one '+' sign in the first expression .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $- \log_a b - \log_a3b$ is the same as $$- (\log_a b + \log_a3b)=-\log(b\times 3b)$$
Alternatively, you could do it like this
$$
- \log_a b - \log_a3b=\log_a\frac1b+\log_a\frac1{3b}
$$
and then continue as you have done.

This is the correct way because that's just how it has been decided that $-$ should work in modern mathematics.

Everything else you've done looks correct to me.

Answer (score 1):

$= log_a (0.5*4a) - (log_a (b*3b)) = log_a (2a) - log_a (3b^2) = log_a ((3b^2)/(2a)) $